# Getting token null on page refresh using firebase.auth().oAuthStateChanged

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication, vuex

i am developing a website where i use Firebase and Vue js. I do state management with vuex. I am stuck when i referesh tha page the token doesn't reload. Until now i havel implemented the a action called autoSignIn he's task is keep user logged after refresh the page. I tried the same way with token, but it seems doesn't work. I can't find out what i am doing wrong? My idea is: when a user refresh the page, it also has to reload the token as do for user authetication.

When reload the page, the program what does is:
Call the getter, and the getter is null. Then call the action autoSignIn.

¿How can i call first autoSignWhen page Refresh for token? Beacause i do same for user authentication and it's work

It is a good paractice to save token in Session storage, cookies or localStorage?

When i sing in for the first time it's wrok fine, but when refresh the page, it show next Error.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Suhfl.png

Here is my auth handler, where i control user auth in page refresh.

```
router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
    const user = await new Promise((resolve) => {
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(async user => {
             await store.dispatch("autoSignIn", user),
            resolve(user)
        });

    });
```

Inside autoSignIn i implemented the code to commit token in state.

```
 autoSignIn ({commit},payload) {

            if (payload !== null){
                commit('setUser',{email:payload.email, userId:payload.uid})
                payload.getIdTokenResult(true).then(token =>{
                    commit('setToken',token)
                    console.log(token)
                })
            }

        },
```

Here is my getter of token:

``````
 getToken:(state) => {
            return state.token !== null && state.user !== null ? state.token : null
        }
`````

I use getter in this action to retrieve certain depending on user role.

`````
getEventsByUser({getters,commit}){
            let data = [];

                if (getters.getToken.claims.admin) {
                    firebase.database().ref('usuario')
                        .on('value',event =>{
                            event.forEach(user =>{
                                user.child('eventos').forEach(evento =>{
                                    data.push({ "id": evento.key, ...evento.val() })
                                })
                            });
                            commit('setEventsByUser',data)
                        });

                }else if( getters.getToken.claims.student){
                    firebase.database().ref('usuario/' + getters.isAuthenticated.userId + '/eventos/')
                        .on("value", eventos =>{
                            eventos.forEach(evento =>{
                                data.push({"id":evento.key, ...evento.val()})
                            });
                            commit('setEventsByUser',data)
                        })
                }


        }
````

This is my componente from where i call the action getEventByUser for getting data.
````
computed:{
            getEventsByUser(){
                return  this.$store.getters.getEventsByUser;
            },

        },

        mounted() {
            this.$store.dispatch('getEventsByUser')
        },
````
``````

Answer (score 1):

In order for you to actually make the token consitant throughout the application you can store the token in local storage once you login.

```
const token = res.data.access_token;
localStorage.setItem('access_token', token);
```

Everytime you reload the page you can take the token from local storage and save it vuex. You can create a js file under plugins and have the below code in it.

```
export default ({store}) => {

  const token = localStorage.getItem('access_token') || null;

  store.commit('retrieveToken', token);

}
```

Comment: Hi @Sudam!! I don't want to store in local storage, i sant that, on refresh page load from firebase server.

Comment: This post was a life saver.  Thank you!  In several places they tell you to use claims in the token for access control, but the normal login flows don't behave correctly when you do use them.  Thank you for pointing out this work around for this huge gotcha in firebase.